# Sox fails to identify output filename

Tags: sox

I'm trying to resample with sox, but it keeps yelling at me that it can't find an input file, which makes sense because the file it's looking for is the output file, and therefore doesn't exist.

Here is what I am trying to run

> sox sound.wav -r 11025 sound_resampled.wav polyphase

and the error that I get is

> sox FAIL formats: can't open input file 'sound_resampled.wav': No such file or directory

Any ideas?

Comment: I have no mention of `polyphase` in my sox man-page, what version of sox are you using?

Comment: sox --version and sox -h return sox v. It looks like polyphase was depreciate at some point, which would make sense since the script that is calling sox is pretty ancient.

Answer (score 2):

Working off of Thor's comment, I found that polyphase has been depreciated since at least 2008. Replacing 'polyphase' with 'rate' seems to do the trick.